# Exporting GeoDataFrame object with multi geometry columns to GeoJSON file

Tags: geojson, export, geopandas

Is there a way to export GeoPandas GeoDataFrame with multiple geometry columns to a GeoJSON file? I tried the following but it gave an error:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

# Sample data for the GeoDataFrame
data = {
    'City': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago'],
    'Population': [8500000, 4000000, 2700000],
    'Coordinates': [Point(-74.006, 40.7128), Point(-118.2437, 34.0522), Point(-87.6298, 41.8781)],
    'Route': [LineString([(40, -74), (41, -75), (42, -76)]), 
              LineString([(34, -118), (35, -119), (36, -120)]), 
              LineString([(41, -87), (42, -88), (43, -89)])]
}

# Create a GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry='Coordinates')

# Add the second geometry column 'Route' to the GeoDataFrame
gdf['Route'] = gdf['Route'].apply(lambda x: x if not x.is_empty else None)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf, geometry='Route')

# Specify the path where you want to save the GeoJSON file
geojson_path = 'path/to/output/file.geojson'

# Export the GeoDataFrame to a GeoJSON file
gdf.to_file(geojson_path, driver='GeoJSON')
```

I received the following error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-04a88527afe1> in <cell line: 25>()
     23 
     24 # Export the GeoDataFrame to a GeoJSON file
---> 25 gdf.to_file(geojson_path, driver='GeoJSON')

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/geopandas/io/file.py in convert_type(column, in_type)
    638             out_type = types[str(in_type)]
    639         else:
--> 640             out_type = type(np.zeros(1, in_type).item()).__name__
    641         if out_type == "long":
    642             out_type = "int"

TypeError: Cannot interpret '<geopandas.array.GeometryDtype object at 0x7d0d57a44bb0>' as a data type
```

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert one of the geometry columns to a [wkt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) string:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

# Sample data for the GeoDataFrame
data = {
    'City': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago'],
    'Population': [8500000, 4000000, 2700000],
    'Coordinates': [Point(-74.006, 40.7128), Point(-118.2437, 34.0522), Point(-87.6298, 41.8781)],
    'Route': [LineString([(40, -74), (41, -75), (42, -76)]), 
              LineString([(34, -118), (35, -119), (36, -120)]), 
              LineString([(41, -87), (42, -88), (43, -89)])]
}

# Create a GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, geometry='Coordinates')

# Add the second geometry column 'Route' to the GeoDataFrame
gdf['Route'] = gdf['Route'].apply(lambda x: x if not x.is_empty else None)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(gdf, geometry='Route')

gdf["Coordinates"] = gdf.apply(lambda x: x["Coordinates"].wkt, axis=1)

geojson_path = '/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/file.geojson'
gdf.to_file(geojson_path, driver='GeoJSON')
```

And when you read the file, restore the wkt string to a geometry with shapely.wkt.loads:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import wkt
geojson_path = '/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/file.geojson'
df = gpd.read_file(geojson_path)
df.dtypes
# City             object
# Population        int64
# Coordinates      object
# geometry       geometry
# dtype: object

df["Coordinates"] = df.apply(lambda x: wkt.loads(x["Coordinates"]), axis=1)
df.dtypes
# City             object
# Population        int64
# Coordinates    geometry
# geometry       geometry
# dtype: object
```

Or create a geometry collection and keep `Population` and `Coordinates` as string columns:

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data)
gdf["geometry"]=gdf.apply(lambda x: GeometryCollection([Point(x["Coordinates"]), LineString(x["Route"])]), axis=1).set_crs("epsg:4326")
gdf = gdf.astype({"City":str, "Population":int, "Coordinates":str, "Route":str})
gdf.to_file('/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/file_geometrycollection.geojson')
```